# AES ofb decryption in C

Tags: c, encryption, aes

I'm playing with AES encryption and I've encountered this problem. I found a code example somewhere around the net and I tried to play with it. (I'm using Gladman AES library)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "aes.h"

void encrypt(const char *fileIn, const char *fileOut, const unsigned char *key);

void decrypt_string(const char *fileIn, const unsigned char *key);

int main() {

  const unsigned char key[] = "password";
  srand(time(NULL));
  aes_init();
  encrypt("TEST.raw", "TEST.raw.encrypted", key);
  decrypt_string("TEST.raw.encrypted", key);
  return 0;
}

void encrypt(const char *fileIn, const char *fileOut, const unsigned char *key) {
  int i;
  aes_encrypt_ctx ctx[1];
  unsigned char iv[16]; /* initialisation vector */
  unsigned char inBuffer[200], outBuffer[200];
  FILE *inFile = fopen(fileIn, "rb");
  FILE *outFile = fopen(fileOut, "wb");

  /* pick a random initialisation vector */

  for(i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
    iv[i] = rand() & 0xFF;
  fwrite(iv, 1, 16, outFile);

  aes_encrypt_key256(key, ctx);
  while((i = fread(inBuffer, 1, sizeof(inBuffer), inFile)) > 0) {
    aes_ofb_encrypt(inBuffer, outBuffer, i, iv, ctx);
    fwrite(outBuffer, 1, i, outFile);
  }

  aes_ofb_encrypt(inBuffer, outBuffer, i, iv, ctx);
  fwrite(outBuffer, 1, i, outFile);
  fclose(inFile);
  fclose(outFile);
}

void decrypt_string(const char *fileIn, const unsigned char *key) {
  int i,j;
  aes_encrypt_ctx ctx[1];
  unsigned char iv[16]; /* initialisation vector */
  unsigned char inBuffer[200], outBuffer[200];
  FILE *inFile = fopen(fileIn, "rb");
  //FILE *outFile = fopen(fileOut, "wb");
  /* read initialization vector from file */
  if(fread(iv, 1, 16, inFile) < 16)
    return; /* error: file doesn't even contain an initialisation vector */

  aes_encrypt_key256(key, ctx);
  while((i = fread(inBuffer, 1, sizeof(inBuffer), inFile)) > 0) {
    aes_ofb_decrypt(inBuffer, outBuffer, i, iv, ctx);
    printf("%s", outBuffer);
  }

  fclose(inFile);
}
```

Now everything works fine like this, the file gets decrypted correctly.

But when I take the encrypted file and try to decrypt it again using the decrypt_string() function it doesn't decrypt correctly. It works only while the program is running. Now I have been searching and found comments in aes.h, it probably has something to do with aes_mode_reset(). But I am just learning so I don't understand it much. So I'll appreciate any help I can get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `key` includes garbage. An AES256 key is not a string; it is exactly 32 bytes of binary data. You're passing eight bytes ("password") plus the next 24 bytes that happen to be on the stack.

You cannot pass a human-provided password to `aes_encrypt_key256()`. You need to first convert it to a key using PBKDF2 or another Key Derivation Function (such as bcrypt or scrypt). [BSD](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/lib/libutil/pkcs5_pbkdf2.c?rev=HEAD) has one of many PBKDF2 implementations in C.